# Need help identifying this plant

Tags: identification, plant-care, weeds

I found this strange plant growing around my garden, like a weed, but never seen it before. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a picture?

Comment: Hi! I see you've been around the network, but this is your first post here, so, welcome! I re-loaded the picture because we hadn't been able to see it. Let me know if it's not the right image. Where do you live? Knowing that can help us identify your plant. I notice you chose vegetables as a tag. Is it in a vegetable garden? Does it resemble any other vegetables you've seen or are growing? Thanks!

Comment: Could it be a conifer seedling?

Comment: The picture is right, Sue, thanks! I live in Vancouver,British Columbia,Canada, and I chose vegetables as a tag because it is in a vegetabke garden. I doubt it to be a conifer seedling although it definitely resembles it. I had a suggestion that it is an asparagus plant, which is interesting as some asparagus seedlings do look like that. Still open to suggestions thanks a lot for your insights so far!Appreciate it!

Comment: Related or duplicates: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/19740/my-new-allotment-plot-is-covered-in-horsetail http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/10962/how-to-control-horsetails-equisetum

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is Equisetum arvense, the field horsetail or common horsetail. It is a herbaceous perennial plant, native throughout the arctic and temperate regions of the northern hemisphere. ~Wikipedia

[image]

Benefits: http://www.herbwisdom.com/herb-horsetail.html

Eradication: http://extension.psu.edu/plants/green-industry/news/2012/weed-of-the-month-field-horsetail-equisetum-arvense

Comment: Even seeing a picture makes me shudder. They will be popping up in my garden in a few weeks.